# Developing a Bluemix app that is a backend for an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, server, ibm-cloud

I am making an app that allows the user to upload photos and videos into the Bluemix server and classify it under a certain category. Another user who subscribed to that category would be able to see what the user uploaded. I have connected my iOS app to Bluemix. So how would i do this from the backend of the server without having any code in my Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Mobile Backend as a Service to accomplish this.  Check out [this](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2015/01/08/mbaas-ibm-mobile-cloud-services-bluemix-mobilefirst/) for more info on how to do it.

Comment: Is it possible for me to allow the user to upload videos and pics by coding in the backend?

Comment: Yep, I would use the object store service though instead...  It is just Openstack Swift, there is lots of libraries out there for that.